# Html.DropDownListFor selectedvalue not showing on postback

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In my view, there are 5 dropdownlists. The first one is populated when the user first gets to the page. Then the rest of the dropdowns are populated based on what they select from the dropdowns. The binding of the dropdowns work fine..no problem. Basically, there is a submit button on the page which displays the results from the values selected from the dropdowns. The problem is on HttpPost, whatever was selected from the dropdown, they disappear. The other thing is while i keep changing the selectedvalue and do submit, they show up.

For example, i select values from each of the dropdowns. Do a submit, the results display and only the first one shows the selected value. The rest are gone. Then on the same time, I select the remaining values, do a submit, now the first and second show up and the rest are gone. I repeat the same thing, do a postback and the 1st, second and thrid show up and the remaining are gone. Not sure whats happening here. Let me know if I would need to update this post with my code. Just wanted to check if there is quick fix before i post what i did.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select#NationId').change(function () {
            var nationId = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'LoadAreas',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify({ nationId: nationId }),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('select#AreaId').get(0).options.length = 0;
                    $('select#AreaId').append('<option value="0">Select All</option>');
                    $.each(data, function (val, Areas) {
                        $('select#AreaId').append('<option value="' + Areas.Id + '">' + Areas.Name + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        $('select#AreaId').change(function () {
            var areaId = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'LoadDistricts',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify({ areaId: areaId }),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('select#DistrictId').get(0).options.length = 0;
                    $('select#DistrictId').append('<option value="0">Select All</option>');
                    $.each(data, function (val, Districts) {
                        $('select#DistrictId').append('<option value="' + Districts.Id + '">' + Districts.Name + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        $('select#DistrictId').change(function () {
            var districtId = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'LoadTerritoryManagers',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify({ districtId: districtId }),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('select#TMId').get(0).options.length = 0;
                    $('select#TMId').append('<option value="0">Select All</option>');
                    $.each(data, function (val, TMManagers) {
                        $('select#TMId').append('<option value="' + TMManagers.Id + '">' + TMManagers.Name + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        $("#TMId").change(function () {
            var tmId = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'LoadDealers',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify({ tmId: tmId }),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#ChannelId").get(0).options.length = 0;
                    $("#ChannelId").append('<option value="0">Select All</option>');
                    $.each(data, function (val, SurveyDealers) {
                        $("#ChannelId").append('<option value="' + SurveyDealers.Id + '">' + SurveyDealers.DealerId + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div style="width: 100%; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
        <div align="right" style="padding-top: 10px;">
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to Reports page", "Index", "Reports/Customers", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "PremireButton" })
        </div>
        <h3  style="background-color: #CC0000; color: #fff; font-size: 1.5em;">
            Customer Survey Report</h3>
        <table width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding: 10px 0 5px 5px;">
            @if (Model.ShowNational)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;">
                        <b>Select a Country:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NationId, Model.NationalChannelGroups, "Select All")
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            @if (Model.ShowArea)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;">
                        <b>Select an Area:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AreaId, Model.AreaChannelGroups, "Select All")
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            @if (Model.ShowDistrict)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;">
                        <b>Select a District:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DistrictId, Model.DistrictChannelGroups, "Select All")
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            @if (Model.ShowTM)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;">
                        <b>Select a TM:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TMId, Model.TMChannelGroups, "Select All")
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;">
                    <b>Select a Dealer:</b>
                </td>
                <td style="padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ChannelId, Model.Channels, "Select All")
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Submit" class="PremierSubmitButton" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        @if (Model.ShowCustomerReport)
        {
        if (Model.Report.Count() > 0)
        {
            <table id="SurveyResponse" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 11px;">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="header">
                        <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
                            Dealer #
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
                            District
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
                            TM
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
                            Survey Code
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
                            First Name
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
                            Last Name
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
                            Address
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
                            City
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
                            State
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
                            Postal Code
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
                            Phone
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
                            Mail Sent
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
                            Email Sent
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @{bool alternate = false;}
                    @foreach (var tr in Model.Report)
                    {
                        <tr @(alternate ? "class=alternate" : "")>
                            <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
                                @tr.DealerId
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
                                @tr.District
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">@tr.TM
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">@tr.SurveyCode
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">@tr.FirstName
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">@tr.LastName
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">@tr.Address
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">@tr.City
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">@tr.State
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">@tr.PostalCode
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">@tr.Phone
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">@(tr.MailSent.HasValue ? @tr.MailSent.Value.ToShortDateString() : String.Empty)
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">@(tr.DateCompleted.HasValue ? @tr.DateCompleted.Value.ToShortDateString() : String.Empty)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                           alternate = !alternate;
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
        else
        {
            <text>There are no records to display</text>
        }
       }
    </div>
}
```

Here is my HttpPost

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CustomerReport(AreaManagerModel model)
    { 
         //Display Result here
         LoadDropDowns(model);
         return View("CustomerReport", model);
    }

private void LoadDropDowns(AreaManagerModel model)
    {
        var user = db.Users.Find(SessionHandler.CurrentUser.UserId);
        model.TMChannelGroups = new List<SelectListItem>();
        model.Channels = new List<SelectListItem>();
        model.AreaChannelGroups = new List<SelectListItem>();
        model.NationalChannelGroups = new List<SelectListItem>();
        model.DistrictChannelGroups = new List<SelectListItem>();

        var _signedInChannelGroupId = from s in user.ChannelGroups
                                      select s;
        if (_signedInChannelGroupId.Count() > 0)
            model.LoggedChannelGroupId = _signedInChannelGroupId.Select(m => m.ChannelGroupId).First();

        var org = (from o in user.ManagedOrganizations
                   //where o.OrganizationId == 4
                   where o.OrganizationId == 8
                   select o).FirstOrDefault();
        if (org != null || user.IsSuperUser)
        {
            model.ShowNational = true;
            model.ShowArea = true;
            model.ShowDistrict = true;
            model.ShowTM = true;

            model.NationalChannelGroups = from i in db.ChannelGroups
                                          //where i.ChannelGroupTypeId == 4
                                          where i.ChannelGroupTypeId == 6
                                          select new SelectListItem()
                                          {
                                              Text = i.Name,
                                              Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)i.ChannelGroupId)
                                          };
            if (model.NationId != 0)
            {
                var ngroup = (from g in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroups
                              //where g.ChannelGroupTypeId == 4
                              where g.ChannelGroupTypeId == 6
                              select g).FirstOrDefault();
                if (ngroup != null)
                {
                    model.AreaChannelGroups = from i in ngroup.Children
                                              select new SelectListItem()
                                              {
                                                  Text = i.Name,
                                                  Value = i.ChannelGroupId.ToString()
                                              };
                }
                var agroup = (from g in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroups
                              where g.ChannelGroupTypeId == 1
                              select g).FirstOrDefault();
                if (agroup != null)
                {
                    model.DistrictChannelGroups = from i in agroup.Children
                                                  select new SelectListItem()
                                                  {
                                                      Text = i.Name,
                                                      Value = i.ChannelGroupId.ToString()
                                                  };
                }
                var dgroup = (from g in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroups
                              where g.ChannelGroupTypeId == 2
                              select g).FirstOrDefault();
                if (dgroup != null)
                {
                    model.TMChannelGroups = from i in dgroup.Children
                                            select new SelectListItem()
                                            {
                                                Text = i.Name,
                                                Value = i.ChannelGroupId.ToString()
                                            };
                }
                var tgroup = (from g in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroups
                              where g.ChannelGroupTypeId == 3
                              select g).FirstOrDefault();
                if (tgroup != null)
                {
                    model.Channels = from i in tgroup.GetAllChannels()
                                     select new SelectListItem()
                                     {
                                         Text = i.ExternalChannelId,
                                         Value = i.ChannelId.ToString()
                                     };
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var ngroup = (from g in user.ChannelGroups
                          //where g.ChannelGroupTypeId == 4
                          where g.ChannelGroupTypeId == 6
                          select g).FirstOrDefault();
            if (ngroup != null)
            {
                model.ShowNational = false;
                model.ShowArea = true;
                model.ShowDistrict = true;
                model.ShowTM = true;

                model.AreaChannelGroups = from i in ngroup.Children
                                          select new SelectListItem()
                                          {
                                              Text = i.Name,
                                              Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)i.ChannelGroupId)
                                          };
                if (model.AreaId != 0)
                {
                    var agroup = (from g in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroups
                                  where g.ChannelGroupTypeId == 1
                                  select g).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (agroup != null)
                    {
                        model.DistrictChannelGroups = from i in agroup.Children
                                                      select new SelectListItem()
                                                      {
                                                          Text = i.Name,
                                                          Value = i.ChannelGroupId.ToString()
                                                      };
                    }
                    var dgroup = (from g in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroups
                                  where g.ChannelGroupTypeId == 2
                                  select g).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (dgroup != null)
                    {
                        model.TMChannelGroups = from i in dgroup.Children
                                                select new SelectListItem()
                                                {
                                                    Text = i.Name,
                                                    Value = i.ChannelGroupId.ToString()
                                                };
                    }
                    var tgroup = (from g in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroups
                                  where g.ChannelGroupTypeId == 3
                                  select g).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (tgroup != null)
                    {
                        model.Channels = from i in tgroup.GetAllChannels()
                                         select new SelectListItem()
                                         {
                                             Text = i.ExternalChannelId,
                                             Value = i.ChannelId.ToString()
                                         };
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var agroup = (from g in user.ChannelGroups
                              where g.ChannelGroupTypeId == 1
                              select g).FirstOrDefault();
                if (agroup != null)
                {
                    model.ShowNational = false;
                    model.ShowArea = false;
                    model.ShowDistrict = true;
                    model.ShowTM = true;
                    model.DistrictChannelGroups = from i in agroup.Children
                                                  select new SelectListItem()
                                                  {
                                                      Text = i.Name,
                                                      Value = i.ChannelGroupId.ToString()
                                                  };
                    if (model.DistrictId != 0)
                    {
                        var dgroup = (from g in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroups
                                      where g.ChannelGroupTypeId == 2
                                      select g).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (dgroup != null)
                        {
                            model.TMChannelGroups = from i in dgroup.Children
                                                    select new SelectListItem()
                                                    {
                                                        Text = i.Name,
                                                        Value = i.ChannelGroupId.ToString()
                                                    };
                        }
                        var tgroup = (from g in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroups
                                      where g.ChannelGroupTypeId == 3
                                      select g).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (tgroup != null)
                        {
                            model.Channels = from i in tgroup.GetAllChannels()
                                             select new SelectListItem()
                                             {
                                                 Text = i.ExternalChannelId,
                                                 Value = i.ChannelId.ToString()
                                             };
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var dgroup = (from g in user.ChannelGroups
                                  where g.ChannelGroupTypeId == 2
                                  select g).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (dgroup != null)
                    {
                        model.ShowNational = false;
                        model.ShowArea = false;
                        model.ShowDistrict = false;
                        model.ShowTM = true;
                        model.TMChannelGroups = from i in dgroup.Children
                                                select new SelectListItem()
                                                {
                                                    Text = i.Name,
                                                    Value = i.ChannelGroupId.ToString()
                                                };
                        if (model.TMId != 0)
                        {
                            var tgroup = (from g in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroups
                                            where g.ChannelGroupTypeId == 3
                                            select g).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (tgroup != null)
                        {
                            model.Channels = from i in tgroup.GetAllChannels()
                                             select new SelectListItem()
                                             {
                                                 Text = i.ExternalChannelId,
                                                 Value = i.ChannelId.ToString()
                                             };
                        }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var tgroup = (from g in user.ChannelGroups
                                      where g.ChannelGroupTypeId == 3
                                      select g).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (tgroup != null)
                        {
                            model.ShowNational = false;
                            model.ShowArea = false;
                            model.ShowDistrict = false;
                            model.ShowTM = false;
                            model.Channels = from i in tgroup.GetAllChannels()
                                             select new SelectListItem()
                                             {
                                                 Text = i.ExternalChannelId,
                                                 Value = i.ChannelId.ToString()
                                             };
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadAreas(int nationId)
    {
        var _Areas = (from c in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroups
                      join cgt in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroupTypes on c.ChannelGroupTypeId equals cgt.ChannelGroupTypeId
                      where cgt.Name == "Area" && c.ParentChannelGroupId == nationId
                      select new AreaName() { Id = c.ChannelGroupId, Name = c.Name }).OrderBy(m => m.Name);

        if (_Areas == null)
            return Json(null);
        List<AreaName> managers = (List<AreaName>)_Areas.ToList();

        return Json(managers);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadDistricts(int areaId)
    {
        var _Districts = (from c in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroups
                    join cgt in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroupTypes on c.ChannelGroupTypeId equals cgt.ChannelGroupTypeId
                    where cgt.Name == "District" && c.ParentChannelGroupId == areaId
                    select new DistrictName() { Id = c.ChannelGroupId, Name = c.Name }).OrderBy(m => m.Name);

        if (_Districts == null)
            return Json(null);

        List<DistrictName> managers = (List<DistrictName>)_Districts.ToList();
        return Json(managers);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadTerritoryManagers(int districtId)
    {
        var _TMS = (from c in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroups
                    join cgt in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroupTypes on c.ChannelGroupTypeId equals cgt.ChannelGroupTypeId
                    where cgt.Name == "Territory" && c.ParentChannelGroupId == districtId
                    select new TMManager() { Id = c.ChannelGroupId, Name = c.Name }).OrderBy(m => m.Name);

        if (_TMS == null)
            return Json(null);

        List<TMManager> managers = (List<TMManager>)_TMS.ToList();
        return Json(managers);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadDealers(int tmId)
    {
        var _dealers = (from c in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.Channels
                    where c.ChannelGroupId == tmId
                    select new SurveyDealer() { Id = c.ChannelId, DealerId = c.ExternalChannelId }).OrderBy(m => m.DealerId);

        if (_dealers == null)
            return Json(null);

        List<SurveyDealer> dealers = (List<SurveyDealer>)_dealers.ToList();
        return Json(dealers);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see your View code to start with, that should help.

UPDATE:

Your render code:

```
DropDownListFor(m => m.TMId, Model.TMChannelGroups, "Select All")
```

Is forcing the DropDownBox to select the value "Select All" regardless of what the value of TMId is.

Get rid of that last paremeter entirely and instead change your server-side code to return a SelectList object with 0/Select All as the first SelectListItem.  Then, your model object will properly choose the correct option from the DropDownList.

Comment: Hi Ben, i have edited my post above with the code from my view.

Comment: @Ben Finkel, please use the comments section for this kind of *comments*. The answers section should be used when you actually want to answer a question.

Comment: @Darin I apologize, I actually thought that is what I clicked.

@Bladerunner - How about your controller action that handles the HttpPost.  What does that look like?

Comment: @Ben i have added my HttpPost in the post above. Please let me know if you need anything. Thanks!

Comment: Probably i didn't write the complete code, did I? Its updated now.

Comment: @Ben, yes you are right. The jquery clears out on the change event, thats why i had to call that LoadDropDowns helper method to load the dropdowns again. It could be something with my onchange methods. I have updated my post above with the code.

Comment: @Bladerunner when you say the DropDownLists disappear do you mean that the text selection in the object is blanked out totally or just reverts to "Select All" ?

Comment: its the value that was selected prior to postback..the dropdownlist is filled with all the values, its just the selected value comes with Select All..

Comment: The only thing in your code that sets values to "Select All" is the Razor syntax "Html.DropDownListFor".  I think you're using that wrong.

Comment: Hi Ben, how would i add Select All to my IENumerable<SelectListItem> on the server side?

Comment: Hi Ben, i have resolved the problem. The problem was with my LoadDropDowns method. For District and TMs, I was getting all of them without passing in the selected ids. Thats why, it couldn't bind those selected value for the respective dropdowns. It was more a user error than anything with the javascript. Thanks a lot for your replies. I will go ahead and mark your post as answer..want to give you the credit for helping me out here. Thanks!!

Comment: Ok, glad you were able to figure it out!